# Magento 2: Change the bestseller report count more than 5 items

Tags: magento2, reports, best-seller, change

How to change the bestseller report items number more than 5 items Magento 2?

Thank In Advance..!

Comment: Are you trying to display best seller products using CMS Page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple, you just need to add below code in your `di.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" />
</config>
```

Now create Block file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_ratingLimit = 15; //change Default Limit Number here as you want
    }
}
```

Just set Default Limit in `__construct()` and run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but I need to use the bestseller collection in another place not at the backend  dashboard tabs

Comment: Where you want that ? Let me know I'll check that.

Comment: I need to show theme at the frontend and just I am getting the bestseller product ids and i using them in another collection

Comment: Okay let me check and get back to you

Comment: I've updated my answer @RobertBaum. Please review that and let me know if it works for you then. I have tested that here and working

Comment: If not working in above case then let me know I will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection` class in your custom module and set `$_ratingLimit` as per your requirement. Please check the below code for your reference.

> Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection {

    /**
     * Rating limit
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_ratingLimit = 500;

}
```

> Vendor\Modul\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" />
</config>
```

> Edit:

After adding these files in your custom module, please run below commands:

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Thanks, I added it but it still gets 5 items

Comment: Have you run the post-deployment commands as well? I've used the same code on a website and it is working fine.

Comment: post deployment ? static deploy !

Comment: I updated my answer for the same. Please check.

Comment: Thanks, the problem that I had `di.xml` file under `etc` directory directly and I added a new one under `adminhtml` directory, but  when I added the reference to the under `etc` directly one, the code worked